# Is "Diskursabfolge" a real word that is understood?

Tags: single-word-request, english-to-german

My email software [GroupWise](http://www.novell.com/products/groupwise/) has an option to display a discussion thread. This option is named *"Diskursabfolge"* in the German language version.

Googling for this term revealed 168 hits only, half of those intimately connected to GroupWise.

This makes me believe that we have a non-existing term here that may have been introduced by a software company for reasons I can not comprehend.

Does anybody have an idea why this was done? May it be that there is a similar term in English that would have misled them to this translation? What better term should have been used instead? Or is *"Diskursabfolge"* actually a known word that I have missed before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Diskursabfolge - lovely word. I like it. But I would have never used it as "discussion thread". More for bitching people having a heated dispute ;)

Some people do not like English words in the German language, so they make up new ones for established foreign words (E-Post -> E-Mail).

Maybe that is the reason or the translation department just translated everything on their list without thinking about it. That happens for several reasons, most of them are not the fault of the translation department.

But there exists already a German word for "discussion thread" and that's "[Diskussionsfaden](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=Diskussionsfaden)". It's a word by word translation and often used (not known by the Duden yet).

So just install the English version of your software and forget about "Diskursabfolge". ;)

Answer (score 5):

> What better term should have been used instead?

Several E-Mail programs I have used use the term *Unterhaltung*.

Comment: „Unterhaltung" halte ich in dem Zusammenhang für eine eher missglückte Übersetzung von "conversation"; wahrscheinlich war sich der GUI-Übersetzer auch nicht der begrifflichen Nähe zu Unterhaltung im Sinne von "entertainment" bewusst. Daher fände ich einen neutraleren / abstrakteren Begriff besser: eher noch „Gespräch“ oder „Diskussion“ - oder besser gleich den bereits genannten „Diskussionsfaden“.

Comment: Das kann man sicher so sehen - auf der anderen Seite ist es sicher kein Zufall, dass ich diesen Begriff schon mehrfach gesehen habe. Ich wäre auch nie auf die Idee gekommen, ihn mit Unterhaltung im Sinne von Entertainment zu verbinden :)

Comment: PHP BB benutzt als übersetzung von Thread: "Thema" ... nur so als Idee. "Unterhaltung" finde ich aber auch gut und ich halte ein Verwechslung (entertainment) für unwahrscheinlich.

Comment: Thema ist für ein Forum sicher passend. Wenn man aber seine Emails sortiert (nicht eine Newsgroup), halte ich Diskussionsfaden und auch Thema für ungeeignet - letztendlich *unterhält* man sich ja auch per E-Mail. "Normale" Begriffe sind in der Regel kein Fehler , wenn "normale" Leute die Software benutzen - da sind abstrakte Begriffe unglücklich. Das ist etwas, was leider viele Software-Entwickler nicht begreifen. Genauso wenig wie viele nichtprofessionelle Übersetzer nicht verstehen, dass es beim Übersetzen (gerade bei Software) nicht darum geht, möglichst genau an der Vorlage zu bleiben.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it's possible and legal to create new composite words in German, so *Diskursabfolge* is a valid word. It would probably cause most readers to stop and "decode" it, but the meaning would be relatively clear after that.

Still, it's unusual and unnecessary to create this word when there are already more or less established alternatives (see other answers). At the very least, it's poor style and leads to a sub-par user experience.

Answer (score 2):

"Diskursabfolge" is not a word that is in use although it is "legal" to concatenate the two words.

It is quite hard to find a good word that easily conveys the sense. From your short description, I gather that one can toggle between a chronological view of posts and a view grouped by thread.

I would opt for something like "Ordnen nach Thema", but "Diskursabfolge" is not a very bad choice given the constraints.