# Gab es früher mal ein Verb "untergeben"?

Tags: etymology, verb, prefix

Irgendwie hat mich der [Brotaufstrich](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3100/if-brotaufstrich-is-something-they-smear-on-bread-why-fruchtaufstrich-is-no) darauf gebracht, dass folgende Vorsilben

```
ab an auf unter über
```

sich gut mit folgenden Verben kombinieren lassen

```
geben gehen laufen schreiben streichen
```

also

```
abgeben angehen aufgehen untergehen usw.
```

Die einzige Kombination davon, die heute nicht als Verb gebraucht wird ist untergeben.

Aber es gibt ein Substantiv, der **Untergebene**, welches aussieht, als ob es von einem Verb untergeben abgeleitet wäre.

Wurde untergeben früher einmal als Verb gebraucht?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Im [Deutschen Wörterbuch von Jacob und Wilhelm Grimm](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=untergeben) finden sich noch folgende Bedeutungen

> **UNTERGEBEN**, v.:
>     a) in obhut, pflege geben
>     b) unterordnen
>     c) im kartenspiel eine niedrigere karte zugeben
>     d) veraltet als besitz oder eigenthum hingeben

Answer (score 8):

Google kennt neben einem ersten Auftreten um 1650 das Wort ab 1750. Ab 1850 scheint es 'auszusterben'.

[image: Ngram untergeben/Untergebener]
[ngram zu untergeben/Untergebener](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Untergebener%2C+untergeben&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 8):

Untergeben als **Verb** taucht gerne in Kochrezepten auf.

Answer (score 2):

> zu veraltet untergeben = unterordnen, mittelhochdeutsch undergeben, althochdeutsch untargeban

Ja, hat früher "[unterordnen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/untergeben)" bedeutet.

Answer (score 1):

*Was dagegen spricht:*

Besagtes Wort gab es wohl immer nur als Eigenschaftswort, sodass das Konstrukt 'untergeben sein' wiederum ein Verb-Komplex bildet.

('untergeben' ist allerdings analog zu Verben in der 2. Vergangenheit gebildet - wie etwa 'unterbrochen'.)

Wenn Person A des B Untergebener ist, dann ist A dem B untergeben.

*Was dafür spricht:*

Wenn der König K den Ritter R dem Herzog H 'untergibt', dann ist R ein von K dem H untergebener Ritter;
R ist dem H untergeben (worden).

'untergeben' = 'jemanden einem anderen unterstellen'.

Comment: Instead of posting multiple answers you could edit your old answer and add you new thoughts. You may do so if you follow this link: http://german.stackexchange.com/posts/3480/edit

Comment: Or just click on *edit* below your answer ;)

Comment: Habe die beiden Antworten zu einer zusammengeführt.